# DatePicker block out weekends

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to *skip* out weekends on the DatePicker calendar.  The first post below helped me to figure out how to *block* out weekends, however, this on it's own will not work for what I need.

Let me give a couple of examples:

1. Lets say today is Monday.  The best 3 options will show Monday,
   Tuesday & Wednesday.
2. Now lets say today is Thursday.  The next 3 options shown on the calendar will be Thursday, Friday & Monday.
3. Finally lets say today is Saturday.  The next 3 options shown on the calendar will be Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

In other words there should always be 3 days available to select and it should be weekdays only.

```
<script>
//initialise datepicker
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         minDate: 0,
         maxDate: 2
    });
  /*
  $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
  })*/

  $('.cal').on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(this).closest('.calendar').find('.datepicker');
    target.datepicker('show');
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a very dirty hack that you can come over with:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: (function () {
        var today = new Date().getDay(), add = 0;
        switch (today) {
            case 0:
                add = 1;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                add = 2;
                break;
        }
        return 2 + add;
    })()
});
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you, but are there any cleaner solutions?

Comment: @V4n1ll4 I think to need to hack the source of datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jQuery UI Datepicker (other datepickers are available):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 2,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Link to [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends).

`beforeShowDay` accepts a function as callback to determine which days to show, with the function returning either `true` or `false` based on the day. For example, it is possible to supply a custom function to exclude only Sundays.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and it blocks out the weekends.  However, it's not showing the next two available dates.  For example, if I look at the calendar today it should show Friday, Monday and Tuesday